# Cs50 pset2 - only_digits function doesn't print error message when string isn't a digit

Tags: c, cs50

I’ve been stuck on the second part of Pset 2 “checking the key” for weeks.
I believe the issue is with my `only_digit` function.
I’m trying to get the `for` loop in the `only_digits` function, after the first  initialization  to go back to the `for` loop and check the next character if the character is a digit,
else if the character is not a digit I want the program to return `false` and stop the program.

The part that I am really confused by is in my `for` loop I have created an `if` statement inside of it, that I can’t quite understand how to make it go back to the `for` loop after I check if the character is a digit.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

bool only_digits(string s);

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    if (argc == 2) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (argc > 2 || argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //check if argv1 is a digit
    bool check_argv = only_digits(argv[1]);

    //if only_digits(argv[1]) returns false print printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n") and return 1
    if (check_argv == 0) {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

bool only_digits(string s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if (isdigit(s[i])) {
            //if the first char is a digit go on to next char in string 
            return true;
        } else {
            // if first thing is nor a digit go straight to the usage message - no need to check the other letters build an else statement
            return false;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You're only checking the first character of the string. If you find a character that is not a digit immediately return false and only return true at the end of the function after the loop.

Comment: You never do anything. if argc == 2 -> return. if argc <2 || argc > 2 -> return

Comment: You may want to spend some time learning how to format your code for readability. It definitely helps you since readable code is easier to work with and if you need to show it to someone else they will appreciate it.

Comment: [tag:c#] is not [tag:c]! Please use the correct tags

Comment: Thank you all, im new to programming and stack overflow im still learning

Answer (score 1):

In the function `only_digits()`, you should just test if `isdigit(s[i])` is not zero and return `false` immediately if it is, indicating a non digit character:

```
bool only_digits(string s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if (isdigit(s[i]) == 0) {
            // return false if there is at least one non digit character
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note however these remarks:

- computing `strlen(s)` at each iteration is costly.  Instead, you could just test that `s[i] != '\0'`
- `char` arguments to `isdigit()` should be cast as `(unsigned char)` to avoid undefined behavior on non ASCII characters on platforms where `char` is signed.
- empty strings should probably be rejected.
- `if (argc == 2)` is the expected value, do not `return 0;` in this case, instead you should only test `if (argc != 2)`

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

bool only_digits(string s);

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //check if argv1 is an empty string
    if (argv[1][0] == '\0') {
        printf("key must not be empty\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //check if argv1 only has digits
    if (!only_digits(argv[1])) {
        printf("key must only contain digits\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // [...]
    return 0;
}

bool only_digits(string s) {
    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        unsigned char cc = s[i];
        if (isdigit(cc) == 0) {
            // return false if there is at least one non digit character
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```